# Add a content widget inside a blogger post!

Tags: google, blogger, widgets

I am wondering if it is possible to add a blogger widget (say recent posts widget) within a blog post in blogger.

Any pointers on doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Use widgets that provide HTML and JavaScript, then copy and paste that into your post. To display recent posts, for example, you could sign up for [FeedBurner,](http://feedburner.com) then use the HTML code generated by their [BuzzBoost](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78976) widget (under Publicize>BuzzBoost in the FeedBurner control panel) to display the latest posts from your RSS feed in the blog post itself.